# Admob in Android 2.3

Tags: android, admob, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have an Android app that I am trying to display ads in. The ads display fine on my Galaxy Nexus, running Android 4.1.2, but on my Droid 2, running Android 2.3, they don't display.

I've looked all over the place, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

Android Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/sms_logo_green_w_blue">
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

XML File:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/mediation_id"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, <my device id>"
                ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

I've tried loading the ad through Java code instead of through XML like this:

```
com.google.ads.AdView adView = new com.google.ads.AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, this.getResources().getString(R.string.mediation_id));
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainAdLayout);

// Add the adView to it
layout.addView(adView);

AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
adRequest.addTestDevice("<my device id>");
adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);

adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

No matter what I do, the ads don't load on 2.3. Any ideas?

this is all I see in the logcat from my app or admob:

```
I/Ads     ( 3220): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_getSdkConstants();AFMA_buildAdURL({"kw":[],"preqs":0,"session_id":"16659815784493691135","u_sd":1.5,"seq_num":"1","slotname":"5ae6fdb32cdf4c1a","u_w":320,"msid":"com.havens1515.autorespondfree","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.2.1","mv":"8011016.com.android.vending","isu":"B78F2F5C240A24F31F6EF9D6EBD74706","cipa":1,"bas_off":0,"format":"320x50_mb","oar":0,"net":"wi","app_name":"17.android.com.havens1515.autorespondfree","hl":"en","ad_pos":{"height":0,"visible":0,"y":0,"x":0,"width":0},"gnt":6,"u_h":569,"carrier":"31000","bas_on":0,"ptime":0,"u_audio":1});</script></head><body></body></html>

W/asset   ( 3220): deep redirect failure from 0x0103003e => 0x02060007, defStyleAttr=0x0101006c, defStyleRes=0x01030019, style=0x00000000

D/dalvikvm( 3220): GC_CONCURRENT freed 225K, 49% free 2928K/5639K, external 513K/519K, paused 2ms+7ms

D/dalvikvm( 3220): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 2K, 49% free 2925K/5639K, external 513K/519K, paused 55ms

D/ViewConsistency( 3220): AbsListView android.widget.ListView@40516210 enabled= true

D/ViewConsistency( 3220): AbsListView android.widget.ListView@40516210 enabled= true
```

then

```
I/Ads     ( 3220): To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice("B78F2F5C240A24F31F6EF9D6EBD74706");

I/Ads     ( 3220): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_getSdkConstants();AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":1,"session_id":"16659815784493691135","u_sd":1.5,"seq_num":"2","slotname":"5ae6fdb32cdf4c1a","u_w":320,"msid":"com.havens1515.autorespondfree","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.2.1","mv":"8011016.com.android.vending","isu":"B78F2F5C240A24F31F6EF9D6EBD74706","cipa":1,"bas_off":0,"format":"320x50_mb","oar":0,"net":"wi","app_name":"17.android.com.havens1515.autorespondfree","hl":"en","ad_pos":{"height":0,"visible":0,"y":0,"x":0,"width":0},"gnt":6,"u_h":569,"carrier":"31000","bas_on":0,"ptime":400,"u_audio":1});</script></head><body></body></html>
```

and

```
D/dalvikvm( 3505): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries

W/ActivityThread( 3505): Application com.havens1515.autorespondfree can be debugged on port 8100...

D/szipinf ( 3505): Initializing inflate state

E/dalvikvm( 3505): Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$Builder', referenced from method com.havens1515.autorespondfree.AutoRespond.showNotification

W/dalvikvm( 3505): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 15 (Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;) in Lcom/havens1515/autorespondfree/AutoRespond;

D/dalvikvm( 3505): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0031

D/dalvikvm( 3505): VFY: dead code 0x0033-00cd in Lcom/havens1515/autorespondfree/AutoRespond;.showNotification (Landroid/content/Context;)V

D/dalvikvm( 3505): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 62K, 50% free 2706K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 40ms

I/Database( 3505): sqlite returned: error code = 0, msg = Recovered 14 frames from WAL file /data/data/com.havens1515.autorespondfree/databases/webview.db-wal

I/Database( 3505): sqlite returned: error code = 0, msg = Recovered 18 frames from WAL file /data/data/com.havens1515.autorespondfree/databases/webviewCache.db-wal

I/Ads     ( 3505): To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice("B78F2F5C240A24F31F6EF9D6EBD74706");

W/asset   ( 3505): deep redirect failure from 0x0103003e => 0x02060007, defStyleAttr=0x0101006c, defStyleRes=0x01030019, style=0x00000000

D/dalvikvm( 3505): GC_CONCURRENT freed 204K, 49% free 2926K/5639K, external 513K/519K, paused 2ms+4ms

D/dalvikvm( 3505): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 24K, 49% free 2902K/5639K, external 513K/519K, paused 51ms

I/Ads     ( 3505): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_getSdkConstants();AFMA_buildAdURL({"kw":[],"preqs":0,"session_id":"212234885725326360","u_sd":1.5,"seq_num":"1","slotname":"5ae6fdb32cdf4c1a","u_w":320,"msid":"com.havens1515.autorespondfree","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.2.1","mv":"8011016.com.android.vending","isu":"B78F2F5C240A24F31F6EF9D6EBD74706","cipa":1,"bas_off":0,"format":"320x50_mb","oar":0,"net":"wi","app_name":"17.android.com.havens1515.autorespondfree","hl":"en","ad_pos":{"height":0,"visible":0,"y":0,"x":0,"width":0},"gnt":6,"u_h":569,"carrier":"31000","bas_on":0,"ptime":0,"u_audio":1});</script></head><body></body></html>
D/ViewConsistency( 3505): AbsListView android.widget.ListView@40536910 enabled= true

D/ViewConsistency( 3505): AbsListView android.widget.ListView@40536910 enabled= true

I/Ads     ( 3505): To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice("B78F2F5C240A24F31F6EF9D6EBD74706");

I/Ads     ( 3505): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_getSdkConstants();AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":1,"session_id":"212234885725326360","u_sd":1.5,"seq_num":"2","slotname":"5ae6fdb32cdf4c1a","u_w":320,"msid":"com.havens1515.autorespondfree","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.2.1","mv":"8011016.com.android.vending","isu":"B78F2F5C240A24F31F6EF9D6EBD74706","cipa":1,"bas_off":0,"format":"320x50_mb","oar":0,"net":"wi","app_name":"17.android.com.havens1515.autorespondfree","hl":"en","ad_pos":{"height":0,"visible":0,"y":0,"x":0,"width":0},"gnt":6,"u_h":569,"carrier":"31000","bas_on":0,"ptime":268,"u_audio":1});</script></head><body></body></html>

W/webcore ( 3505): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout

W/webcore ( 3505): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
```

Got the following from logcat when tracking ad behavior:

```
I/Ads     ( 5877): AdLoader timed out after 60000ms while getting the URL.

D/webviewglue( 5877): nativeDestroy view: 0x1e94e8

I/Ads     ( 5877): onFailedToReceiveAd(A network error occurred.)

D/AutoRespondFree( 5877): onFailedToReceiveAd (A network error occurred.)
```

Comment: The code is fine, we need to see LogCat output though. Is there a crash? Is it a network error (no internet on your 2.3 device? AdRequest successful but lack of inventory (you didn't addTestDevice on your 2.3 device and your account isn't yet getting live ads)?

Comment: I have looked at the logcat. There is no crash, there are no errors in the logcat, I had internet on the 2.3 device (connected to wifi, and was receiving email, so it was verified working,) the account is getting live ads already on the 4.1.2 device. I'm completely dumbfounded here. Thanks for trying though :-/

Comment: Can you paste the logs anyways? There has to be something relevant.  If there really is nothing, perhaps a request isn't even being made?

Comment: Looks like you're using a mediation ID? What networks is the ID connected to? I would expect to see additional logs.

Comment: The other ad network I'm using is called "Tap for Tap". I've been working with their tech support for a few issues over the past week or so. They think that this issue may be due to their SDK, but they are still looking into it. Until then, any suggestions would still be much appreciated (since I'm not 100% sure this problem is due to them.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot. I had an adblock app installed on my Droid 2 that I had forgotten about (I haven't used the device in quite some time.)

Sorry for wasting your time! I did vote up your answer though, because it DID help me realize what the issue was.

Answer (score 1):

Have your class implement `AdListener` so that you can get more information in the logs about what's happening with the request.

```
public class MyClass extends Activity implements AdListener {
  private static final String LOG_TAG = "MyClass";

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Get the ad.
    AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

    // Set the AdListener.
    adView.setAdListener(this);

    // Your other code here.
    ...
  }

  /** Called when an ad is clicked and about to return to the application. */
  @Override
  public void onDismissScreen(Ad ad) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDismissScreen");
    Toast.makeText(this, "onDismissScreen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  /** Called when an ad was not received. */
  @Override
  public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad ad, AdRequest.ErrorCode error) {
    String message = "onFailedToReceiveAd (" + error + ")";
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, message);
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  /**
   * Called when an ad is clicked and going to start a new Activity that will
   * leave the application (e.g. breaking out to the Browser or Maps
   * application).
   */
  @Override
  public void onLeaveApplication(Ad ad) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onLeaveApplication");
    Toast.makeText(this, "onLeaveApplication", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  /**
   * Called when an Activity is created in front of the app (e.g. an
   * interstitial is shown, or an ad is clicked and launches a new Activity).
   */
  @Override
  public void onPresentScreen(Ad ad) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onPresentScreen");
    Toast.makeText(this, "onPresentScreen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  /** Called when an ad is received. */
  @Override
  public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onReceiveAd");
    Toast.makeText(this, "onReceiveAd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

Comment: Check my last edit. Got no output from it. No idea what's going on.

Comment: Did you set the adlistener via `adView.setAdListener(this);`?

Comment: Well, it took forever to get anything to happen, but "onFailedToReceiveAd" gave me "A network error occurred."

Comment: Added some more logcat info. I'm heading to bed for the night, I'll check back tomorrow. Thanks for taking the time to try to help me.